# connect and read .MDB item with C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Is it possible to connect to a local MDB file and pick a single bit of info out of it ?
I have a table in a .mbd file with a single bit of info in it. I would like to have that record be output into a disabled textbox for a reference. I believe I can get the DB open, and run the query but no idea what I need to read from it.

thanks

```
var myDataTable = new DataTable();
        using (var conection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=C:\\menus\\newmenus\\menu.mdb;Password=****"))
        {
            conection.Open();
            var query = "Select siteid From n_user";
            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conection);
            OleDbCommandBuilder oleDbCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To simply read a single field on your database table you could use an [OleDbDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.aspx) that could loop over the result and return the field required..

```
var myDataTable = new DataTable();
using (var conection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=C:\\menus\\newmenus\\menu.mdb;Password=****"))
{
     conection.Open();
     var query = "Select siteid From n_user";
     var command = new OleDbCommand(query, conection);
     var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
     while(reader.Read())
         textBox1.Text = reader[0].ToString();

 }
```

if you have just one record and just one field then a better solution is the method [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx)

```
     conection.Open();
     // A query that returns just one record composed of just one field
     var query = "Select siteid From n_user where userid=1";
     var command = new OleDbCommand(query, conection);
     int result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();  // Supposing that siteid is an integer
```

Probably I should also mention that ExecuteScalar returns *null* if the query doesn't find a match for the userid, so it is better to be careful with the conversion here

```
     object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
     if( result != null)
        int userID  = (int)result;
        .....
```

Comment: thanks, yes there is only one row, just holding the sideid record. that should work well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes very possible.  Just have the adapter fill the `DataTable`, also I don't think you'll need the `OleDbCommandBuilder`.

```
    using (var conection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=C:\\menus\\newmenus\\menu.mdb;Password=****"))
    {
        conection.Open();
        var query = "Select siteid From n_user";
        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conection);
        adapter.Fill(myDataTable);
        myTextBox.Text = myDataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    }
```

Also I think using `ExecuteScalar` would be a better solution, but my answer was tailored to the objects you had already instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [OleDbCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx) to retrieve a single value. It is returned as an object and you could cast it to the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for stm like this?

```
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
    // read ur stuff here.
    }
```