# connect and read .MDB item with C# in UWP

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, win-universal-app

I'm developing a UWP application and want to read a MDB file to convert this database to a SQLite database.

I read that i could use `OleDbConnection` to open MS Access database following this topic : [connect and read .MDB item with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906535/connect-and-read-mdb-item-with-c-sharp)

But OleDbConnection is not available in UWP project. It seems not available in `System.data`

Do you know solution to read MDB file in a UWP application programatically?

> **EDIT :**
>
> Microsoft team answered me this information :
>
> Currently, there are no in-box API, or tools compliant third UWP
>   out-of-the-box that allows you to do that.
>
> There is nothing in the roadmap for the moment regarding this point!
>
> I propose you two tracks to explore:
>
> - Convert your .mdb file into sqlite "Ready to use".
> - Develop Web API that exposes the data of your mdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in-box to do this. I'm not aware of any 3rd party libraries that understand .MDBs and supports UWP apps.

I'd convert the .MDB to SQLite from a non-UWP app and then have the UWP app deal only with SQLite.

It looks like there are [many existing tools to do the conversion](https://www.bing.com/search?q=mdb+to+sqlite)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I hope that a solution will be offered one day, in the meantime I'll have to do the manual manipulation as you said