# Read MS access database file (.mdb) in UWP

Tags: ms-access, uwp, win-universal-app

I am working on Universal Windows Application. I want to read ms access database file, But it seems like System.Data.Oledb namespace is not available in UWP.

I don't want to use any Web Service which requires internet connectivity.

Is there any solution for reading MS Access file in UWP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connect and read .MDB item with C# in UWP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904238/connect-and-read-mdb-item-with-c-sharp-in-uwp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no way to do it. Only one avaliable DB format is SQLite.
You can use some [converter tool](https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools)
By the way, soon would be available Entity Framework for SQLite databases (it is in preview now)

Comment: Thanks a lot **Alexej**, I will try converter tool.