# How to connect to MDB file using C# but without any installation

Tags: c#, ms-access, mdbtools

I am developing using C#, and want to open mdb files and query their tables.
But I don't want to use any additional installations (**MS Access Software or MS Access Engine**). Is there any way to do that.
However, **It is very necessary to run the application on AnyCPU with one version of it**. Not one for 32bit neither one for 64bit.
Any Help Please?
With my respect.

**Edit -**
*Someone said this question is answered with this [old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906535/connect-and-read-mdb-item-with-c-sharp) but not!*

The answer is what @GordThompson said in the comments - Thanks again for him.

In details, it is:

```cs
var connectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=" + path + ";";

using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    DataTable Main = new DataTable();
    var cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM Main", connection);
    var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(Main);
}
```

Comment: "It is very necessary to run the application on AnyCPU with one version of it." - Why? The only way to do it without any additional installation is to use the older 32-bit "Jet" driver that ships with Windows. Windows machines can run 32-bit apps, so just produce a 32-bit app and anyone can use it.

Comment: Use `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}` and target your build for 32-bit.